# How to add dynamic symbol layer using mapbox in android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using map box Android SDK in order to use the map.

I'm using symbol layers to add dynamic symbols in the map.

My Code:

```
for (Feature feature : featureCollection.features()) {
String report_id = feature.getStringProperty("report_id");
switch (report_id) {
                        case "1": {
                            Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.mipmap.ic_location_black);
                            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                                if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                                    bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
                                } else {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                }

                                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                                drawable.draw(canvas);
                            }

                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                mapboxMap.getStyle().addImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, bitmap);
                            }
                            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(new SymbolLayer(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)
                                    .withProperties(
                                            iconImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id),
                                            iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                            iconSize(0.7f)
                                    ));
                            break;
                        }
                        case "2": {
                            Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.mipmap.ic_current_pin);
                            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                                if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                                    bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
                                } else {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                }

                                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                                drawable.draw(canvas);
                            }

                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                mapboxMap.getStyle().addImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, bitmap);
                            }
                            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(new SymbolLayer(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)
                                    .withProperties(
                                            iconImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id),
                                            iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                            iconSize(0.7f)
                                    ));
                            break;
                        }
                        case "3": {
                            Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.mipmap.ic_current_location);
                            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                                if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                                    bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
                                } else {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                }

                                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                                drawable.draw(canvas);
                            }

                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                mapboxMap.getStyle().addImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, bitmap);
                            }
                            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(new SymbolLayer(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)
                                    .withProperties(
                                            iconImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id),
                                            iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                            iconSize(0.7f)
                                    ));
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.mipmap.ic_location_transparent);
                            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                                if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                                    bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
                                } else {
                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                }

                                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                                drawable.draw(canvas);
                            }

                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                mapboxMap.getStyle().addImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, bitmap);
                            }
                            mapboxMap.getStyle().addLayer(new SymbolLayer(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id, GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)
                                    .withProperties(
                                            iconImage(MARKER_IMAGE_ID + report_id),
                                            iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                            iconSize(0.7f)
                                    ));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
}
```

But I'm getting all images in all symbols instead of single image in particular single symbol like this

https://www.screencast.com/t/hcoetxj0G

I want to generate single image for single symbol layer.

Please help me who knows the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add bitmap image to mapbox(v10). You can add like this:

```
  val annotationApi = mapView.annotations
            val pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi.createPointAnnotationManager(mapView)
            val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()
                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(i.lon, i.lat))
                .withIconImage(getBitmap(requireContext()))
            pointAnnotationManager.create(pointAnnotationOptions)
```

Here, you should add your longitude and latitude, make sure longitude should come first.

And here, getBitMap() function code below:

```
 private fun getBitmap(context: Context): Bitmap {
        val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.imageId)
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 40, 80, false)
    }
```

You can change the width and height of image from this getBitmap function.
I hope, this help you guys, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I used https://www.diffchecker.com/ and it looks like the only difference between the various sections of your switch/case sections is the mipmap image that you're using. If so, I'd look into using the Maps SDK's match Expression to set the icon. See https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/. I've taken https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/ and adjusted to match what you've got

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.FeatureCollection;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.SymbolLayer;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.get;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.literal;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.match;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.stop;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconImage;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconSize;

/**
 * Display {@link SymbolLayer} icons on the map.
 */
public class BasicSymbolLayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
  OnMapReadyCallback {

  private static final String SOURCE_ID = "SOURCE_ID";
  private static final String ICON_ID = "ICON_ID";
  private static final String LAYER_ID = "LAYER_ID";
  private MapView mapView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
    // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
    Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

    // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_style_basic_symbol_layer);

    mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

    List<Feature> symbolLayerIconFeatureList = new ArrayList<>();
    symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
      Point.fromLngLat(-57.225365, -33.213144)));
    symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
      Point.fromLngLat(-54.14164, -33.981818)));
    symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
      Point.fromLngLat(-56.990533, -30.583266)));

    mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri("mapbox://styles/mapbox/cjf4m44iw0uza2spb3q0a7s41")

        // Add the SymbolLayer icon image to the map style
        .withImage("black_location_icon_id", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_location_black))
        .withImage("current_pin_icon_id", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_current_pin))
        .withImage("current_location_icon_id", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_current_location))
        .withImage("location_transparent_icon_id", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_location_transparent))


        // Adding a GeoJson source for the SymbolLayer icons.
        .withSource(new GeoJsonSource(SOURCE_ID,
            FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(symbolLayerIconFeatureList)))

        // Adding the actual SymbolLayer to the map style. An offset is added that the bottom of the red
        // marker icon gets fixed to the coordinate, rather than the middle of the icon being fixed to
        // the coordinate point. This is offset is not always needed and is dependent on the image
        // that you use for the SymbolLayer icon.
        .withLayer(new SymbolLayer(LAYER_ID, SOURCE_ID)
            .withProperties(
                iconImage(match(get("report_id"), literal("location_transparent_icon_id"),
                    stop(literal("1"), "black_location_icon_id"),
                    stop(literal("2"), "current_pin_icon_id"),
                    stop(literal("3"), "current_location_icon_id"))),
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconIgnorePlacement(true),
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconSize(0.7f)
            )
        ), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
      @Override
      public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

        // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add additional data or make other map adjustments.


      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
}
```

The Maps SDK also has `addOnStyleImageMissingListener`: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/missing-icon/

Also, I'd use the following instead of `mapboxMap.getStyle()`. There's a chance that `mapboxMap.getStyle()` will return `null`.

```
mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
              @Override
              public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

## MapBox Version 10

#### Custom Symbol Layers

To display different types of points of interest, such as restrooms, trailheads, and picnic areas, on the map. To do this, we'll define custom symbols for each POI category and overlay them on the map.

```
mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle(
    styleExtension = style(Style.TRAFFIC_NIGHT) {

        // Define custom images for symbols
        +image(RESTROOMS) {
            bitmap(drawableIdToBitmap(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_rest_rooms))
        }
        +image(TRAIL_HEAD) {
            bitmap(drawableIdToBitmap(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_trail_head))
        }
        +image(PICNIC_AREA) {
            bitmap(drawableIdToBitmap(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_panic_area))
        }

        +symbolLayer(LAYER_ID, SOURCE_ID) {
            sourceLayer(CIRLCE_LAYER_ID)

            // Assign the appropriate icon image based on the POI type
            iconImage(
                switchCase {
                    eq {
                        get {
                            literal(ICON_KEY)
                        }
                        literal(KEY_PICNIC_AREA)
                    }
                    literal(PICNIC_AREA)
                    eq {
                        get {
                            literal(ICON_KEY)
                        }
                        literal(KEY_RESTROOMS)
                    }
                    literal(RESTROOMS)
                    eq {
                        get {
                            literal(ICON_KEY)
                        }
                        literal(KEY_TRAIL_HEAD)
                    }
                    literal(TRAIL_HEAD)
                    // Default case is to return an empty string so no icon will be loaded
                    literal("")
                }
            )
            iconAllowOverlap(true)
            iconAnchor(IconAnchor.BOTTOM)

            // Display text for each POI
            textField(
                Expression.get(TEXT_KEY)
            )
            textColor("#FFFFFF")
        }
    }
)
```

In the code above, we've defined custom images for restroom, trailhead, and picnic area symbols. The `symbolLayer` is used to specify how these symbols are displayed on the map. The `iconImage` property dynamically selects the appropriate icon based on the POI type, and we also display text for each POI.

#### Data Source

To populate our custom symbol layer with data, we need a data source. In this example, we'll use a GeoJSON source with sample data.

```
private val samplejson = """{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-122.4167, 37.7833]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Golden Gate Bridge",
        "POITYPE": "Restroom",
        "TEXT_KEY": "Rest Room"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-122.4084, 37.7833]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Golden Gate Park",
        "POITYPE": "Trailhead",
        "TEXT_KEY": "Trail heading"
      }
    }
  ]
}"""
```

This GeoJSON source contains two features representing points of interest, each with a location, a name, a POI type, and text to display on the map.

```
### Adding the Data to the Map
```

Finally, we add our GeoJSON data to the map and associate it with the symbol layer we defined earlier.

```kotlin
val geoJsonSource = GeoJsonSource.Builder(SOURCE_ID)
    .data(samplejson)
    .build()

val symbolLayer = SymbolLayer(CIRLCE_LAYER_ID, SOURCE_ID)

it.addSource(geoJsonSource)
it.addLayer(symbolLayer)
```

- **Note:**

*use the above code after your Mapbox style extension loaded for example:*

```
mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle(/* above/your-style-extension*/){ it->//you map style there after they get load

val geoJsonSource = GeoJsonSource.Builder(SOURCE_ID)
    .data(samplejson)
    .build()

val symbolLayer = SymbolLayer(CIRLCE_LAYER_ID, SOURCE_ID)

it.addSource(geoJsonSource)
it.addLayer(symbolLayer)
}


private val RESTROOMS = "RESTROOMS"
private val TRAIL_HEAD = "trailhead"
private val PICNIC_AREA = "PICNIC_AREA"


private val KEY_PICNIC_AREA = "Picnic Area"
private val KEY_RESTROOMS = "Restroom"
private val KEY_TRAIL_HEAD = "Trailhead"
private val ICON_KEY = "POITYPE"
private val TEXT_KEY = "TEXT_KEY"

private val CIRLCE_LAYER_ID = "symbol-layer"
private val SOURCE_ID = "SOURCE_ID"
private val LAYER_ID = "LAYER_ID"
```

Now, the custom symbols and text from our GeoJSON source will be displayed on the map based on the POI type.
The above feature geoJson will be shown in San Fransisco